# JBoss EAP 6.4: NoClassDefFoundError on class sun.security.jca.GetInstance

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have a deployment that calls `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance`.

The class `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory` appears to load correctly, but when the method tries to create an instance it throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` on `sun/security/jca/GetInstance`

Looking at the OpenJDK8 sources shows that relevant `javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory` constructor refers explicitly to a method in `sun.security.jca.GetInstance`, so it's normal that it tries to load it.

What's odd is that both `javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.class` and `sun/security/jca/GetInstance.class` are present in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-1.b14.el6.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar` but that only the former is found by the classloader.

What is the jboss module classloader playing at and how can I get it to stop it?

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem, though not quite in the ways suggested above. I wouldn't have got there without the help though (thanks guys).

I did manage to fix the sun/security/jca access problem but it then threw up another problem of a similar type, but with a javax class. I found an ugly fix for that by removing a jar from module org/jboss/genericjms and letting the jdk version get picked up, but I felt that that was playing around too much with stuff that I couldn't predict the consequences of.

The fix I have finally settled on is to put the provided jar that references javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory in a new module all of its own and then to pull in the classes it needs via:

```
    <system export="true">
      <paths>
        <path name="java/sql"/>
        <path name="javax/crypto"/>
        <path name="javax/crypto/spec"/>
        <path name="javax/crypto/interfaces"/>
        <path name="javax/management"/>
        <path name="javax/security/auth/login"/>
        <path name="sun/security/jca"/>
        <path name="org/ietf/jgss"/>
      </paths>
    </system>
```

in the module.xml. When I reference this new module from my code it works (I pulled it in by making it a global module in standalone.xml in fact).

Problem solved. Though I have to say that after this experience of the jboss modular class loader, give me a hierarchical one any day.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Not all JDK classes are exposed to a deployment by default. If your deployment uses JDK classes that are not exposed you can get access to them using `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with system dependencies:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <system export="true">
                <paths>
                    <path name="sun/security/jca"/>
                </paths>
            </system>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Another alternative you can import the whole system module adding the following line to `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Dependencies: system
```

Ref: [Class Loading and Modules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Development_Guide/chap-Class_Loading_and_Modules.html)

Comment: I have already tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything. I initially put it in a war within an ear, but the jboss log contained a line saying it was going to ignore it as it wasn't in the top level. I then moved it to META-INF in the ear, but despite not getting the log message saying it was going to ignore it it seemed to ignore it anyway.

I don't know why,

Comment: @jontyl If you just add them to the top level deployment with `export="true"` then they will be available to everything in the ear.

Comment: It is not working under WildFly10.

My approach is

**<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.3">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
           <module name="sun.jdk"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>**

in **webapp\WEB-INF**

and 

**<path name="sun/security/jca"/>**

in **[WildFly10]/modules/system/layers/base/sun/jdk/main/module.xml**

It is working for me.

Comment: Works in jboss 6.4.9.GA.

Answer (score 1):

In your JBoss installation, go to directory `modules/sun/jdk/main` and edit the `module.xml` file there. In `<dependencies>/<system>/<paths>` add an element `<path name="sun/security/jca"/>`. Restart your JBoss instance and retry.

Comment: This is slightly problematic due to the environment I'm working in - I don't think I will be allowed to change the contents of this file.

I will try creating a new module with just the relevant bits from your suggestion and see if that works (there is facility to add user provided modules).

Comment: @jontyl A lot of "old" sun packages were shut off, you can see that from the included packages in the `module.xml`. I once had to explicitely allow `sun/net` and this was the only way I could do it. However I'm not an expert in JBoss/WildFly, there may be other and better ways.

Comment: @jontyl Did you find a solution to your problem?